# ¿Qué debo hacer cuando me aparece "ModuleNotFoundError" en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con portafolios de inversión.
Este es mi código , y el error me sale en :

VAMOS A IMPORTAR LIBRERÍAS PARA TRABAJAR CON MI DATA FRAME

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyfolio
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfolio'

Comment: Que seria Pyfolio? Un modulo? O un archivo de Python creado por vos?

Comment: suponiendo estás usando windows, desde una ventana de cmd usar: pip install pyfolio , esa es la forma más simple de instalar las bibliotecas

Comment: Si estás tratando de importar un modulo, parece que ese modulo no está instalado. Prueba instalandolo como dijo @tincopasan. Si por otro lado estás importando un archivo de python, revisa que ese archivo exista, se llame `pyfolio` y esté en la misma carpeta que el programa donde importas dicho script.

Comment: Sea cual sea el caso, el error que tienes ocurre debido a que no existe el modulo o script que tratas de importar.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: De nada! Por curiosidad, que hiciste al final???

Comment: Si necesitaba instarlo desde el prompt en anaconda!!